Viewing camera's stream in Motion from another computer
I am trying to stream my USB camera through Motion using Linux 21.2. It sees it through localhost:8080 but I've been trying to disable localhost streaming so I can view it from another computer (laptop) on the same network.
In the configuration file, the locahost stream is off but I can still access it through localhost:8080 and not by searching ip.adress:port on another device.
My configuration:
# Port number used for the webcontrol.
webcontrol_port 8081

# Restrict webcontrol connections to the localhost.
webcontrol_localhost on

# Type of configuration options to allow via the webcontrol.
webcontrol_parms 0

############################################################
# Live stream configuration parameters
############################################################

# The port number for the live stream.
stream_port 8080

# Restrict stream connections to the localhost.
stream_localhost off

